# Advanced test and training time data augmentation on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

As far as I can see tf doesn't includes data augmentations like in torch such as `torchvision.transforms.FiveCrop` and `torchvision.transforms.TenCrop`. What would be the efficent way to implement and connect it to train and test process.

Comment: You can find some useful methods to perform augmentation in the `tf.image` module. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/image).

Comment: There are functions like `tf.image.crop_and_resize` `tf.image.center_crop` but they don't work like `FiveCrop` or `TenCrop`@ShubhamPanchal

Answer (score 0):

Thera are various ways you can implement data augmentations in tensorflow:

1. Object Detection API does this automatically for you, during the training:
   https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto
2. `tf.keras ImageDataGenerator` allows you to apply data augmentations during the training. More speficially, allows you to control the `brightness, rotation, shearing, shifting, zooming, rescaling` etc. You can check more about **ImageDataGenerator** here:  https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/
3. Another thing that I like to do is to create a function that implements my own data augmentation techniques. Then, pass it into `preprocessing_function` of ImageDataGenerator. This way, You can add any data augmentation you can think of. For example, `ImageDataGenerator` lucks of adjusting the contrast in an image. In that case, You can implement it by yourself. I have found this repository, which shows how to implement quite lots of augmentations in **OpenCV & Numpy**:
   https://github.com/kochlisGit/random-data-augmentations